# How to use a subgroup in regex only if it is matched

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am trying to create a regex which matches following(we want to replace all require statements to ES6's import based syntax):

```
const {CtrlOne,
   CtrlTwo} = require("./backend");

var service = "require("./abc/service");
```

and this is what we have currently:

```
(var|let|const)(.*)?([\n\r]*)(.*)(.*=.*)require\((.*)\)(.*)
```

The regex above matches correctly but a new-line character(like in the first statement) is optional. Now I am not sure how do I use this optional subgroup that is being matched to give output as below:

```
import {
  CtrlOne,
  CtrlTwo
} from "./backend";
```

I can get this output also but it seems to create a problem for the statement just after it.
I have create a fork for this https://regexr.com/5bblp
How do I fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try below regex to match. and use `import \2 from \3` to get desired output.

```regex
(var|let|const)([\s\S]*?)=\s*require\((.*)\);
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/o5PPKR/1)